# SSH over Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)

Tags: ssh, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have a need to SSH from a mobile phone over a BLE peripheral to a device running the SSH server.
Namely:

mobile phone (SSH client) ---> BLE peripheral ---> Ethernet (Cat 5) --> device (SSH server)

Is this feasible or even possible?

Given the design of BLE, should we be looking into other transports with higher throughput rates, perhaps Bluetooth classic?

Many thanks

Comment: Use regular Bluetooth...  Look into RFCOMM which is a serial connection over Bluetooth.  BLE has no standard for serial connections.